# Draggabilly not adding event to newly added element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, draggable, jquery-draggable

I'm using [desandro draggabilly](http://draggabilly.desandro.com/) and I'm having a problem when inserting a new element. It seems that the event is not firing on the new element that was added.

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0rr6tmvk/2/).

Here's the code as well.

**HTML**

```
<div class="box draggable">1</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.box {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    display: block;
}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.bridget('draggabilly', Draggabilly);
    var $draggable = $('.draggable').draggabilly({
        axis: 'x'
    });
    $draggable.on('dragEnd', function(e, p) {
        $(this).parent().prepend('<div class="box draggable">2</div>');
        $(this).prev().addClass('draggable')
        $(this).remove();
    }); 
});
```

On the code below when I dragged div 1, on `dragEnd` it will insert div 2 that has a class of `draggable` then remove div 1. The problem here is that div 2 is not being draggable even though it has a class of `draggable`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to re-initialize it after `prepending` since it is added to DOM dynamically and `event draggabilly` will not be attached to it. So below will fix the issue:

```
$draggable.on('dragEnd', function(e, p) {
        $(this).parent().prepend('<div class="box draggable">2</div>');
        $('.draggable').draggabilly({
            axis: 'x'
        }); //re-initialize again
        $(this).remove();
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0rr6tmvk/3/)**

---

**UPDATE**

Now if you want to call `dragend` event to the element you add and keep on incrementing the number on `dragend` just keep a global variable say `i` and increment it everytime as below:

```
var i=1; //global variable
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.bridget('draggabilly', Draggabilly);
    $('.draggable').draggabilly({
        axis: 'x'
    });

    $(document).on('dragEnd','.draggable', function(e, p) {
        i++; //increment it
        $(this).parent().prepend('<div class="box draggable">'+i+'</div>'); 
        //display text as i
        $('.draggable').draggabilly({
            axis: 'x'
        });
        $(this).remove();//remove previous one
    });    
});
```

**[Updated demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/0rr6tmvk/4/)**

Comment: Thanks! It's working but wouldn't there be any performance issue with that approach? Also, it just stops there.. What if I want to add 5 more boxes. Like for every swipe, it'll prepend another box. Like a card swipe.

Comment: @user1781041 Updated answer.. Try the demo and let me know if thats what you are looking for?

Comment: This is working great! Just as expected! Thanks so much!!

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to initialize every time on creation of your div and bind event then
something as below -

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.bridget('draggabilly', Draggabilly);
    var $draggable = $('.draggable').draggabilly({
        axis: 'x'
    });

    $draggable.on('dragEnd', callback);    

});
var co=2;
function callback(e, p) {
        $(this).parent().prepend('<div class="box draggable">'+co++ +'</div>');
        $(this).prev().addClass('draggable')
        $(this).remove();
        $(".draggable").draggabilly({
        axis: 'x'
        });
         $(".draggable").on('dragEnd', callback);
     }
```

**LIVE** http://jsfiddle.net/mailmerohit5/L9kgeu3f/

Comment: This is working great! Just as expected! Thanks so much!!